# My class extends ActionBarActivity for full screen How to Hide and show the ActionBar on touch event

Tags: android, android-activity

> I am new to android, help me. When I click an image, it will show in
>   full screen but on touch it is not showing `ActionBar` and if I touch
>   it should hide `ActionBar` also in full screen mode

```
public void startFullScreen() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        );
    } else {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
}
```

> Thanks

Comment: Do you want to hide action bar when in full screen mode??

Comment: @chandrakanth ya i want to hide and show action bar in full screen on touch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Hiding `ActionBar`:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.hide();
```

And

For Showing `ActionBar`:

```
 ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
 bar.show();
```

~*hope it helps*